# How to implement jquery ajax call client->server method in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Q1:  Can somebody provide code example for jquery ajax to server method call in mvc3?
Q1a: Does the server return have to be a Json result returned from server side?  What are my options with the returned data from the server side method (json, just return a string, etc,)?

-- Something like this...

-- script called from razor view:

```
$("#textbox1).change(function()
{
$.ajax(
    {url: '/controller/action',
    data: { val1: $("#textbox1").val(), val12: ("#textbox2").val()},
    success: function(data){
             $("#SumResult").val(data);
           }})
});
```

-- Server method within same controller:

```
public ActionResult <or> String (int val1, int val2)
{       
    return (i != null && j != null) ? (i + j).ToString() : "";  

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below article should give you an idea :

http://tugberkugurlu.com/archive/working-with-jquery-ajax-api-on-asp-net-mvc-3-0-power-of-json-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views

> Q1a: Does the server return have to be a Json result returned from
>   server side?

No, you can pretty much return anything from server (in ASP.NET MVC world, from controller method). If you return `JSON`, it is pretty much convenient for you to work with it inside your JavaScript code.

> What are my options with the returned data from the server side method
>   (json, just return a string, etc,)?

Some of them are :

- XML
- JSON
- Html

Assuming that your controller supposed to return `ActionResult`, some of that you can return are as follows :

- `Content`
- `Json`